# Want to extract a number included in a path so how to extract 24?

Tags: shell

just wanted to extract a number included in a path path is stored in catalina_home string as "/opt/hpws24/tomcat" so How to extract 24

I tried

```
catahome='/opt/hpws24/tomcat'
version=$(echo "$catalina_home" | grep -o -E '[0-9]+')
echo $version
```

which is giving me 24 but still i want only the number which attached to hpws because my code is giving all the numbers with space separated in case opt or tomcat is having a number sttached in future, So i want only a number attached 2 hpws. please guide me

Answer (score 1):

Problem in OP's attempt is, using `grep` to simply find Digits in whole variable value which may lead to get false positive results too.

With your shown samples/attempts, please try following `awk` program.

```
catahome="/opt/hpws24/tomcat"
echo "$catahome" | awk -F'/' '{sub(/[^0-9]+/,"",$3);print $3}'
```

***Explanation:*** Printing value of string with `echo` command and sending its output as a standard input to `awk` command. In `awk` program, using `-F` option to set field separator as `/` for all the lines. In main program using `sub` function of `awk` to substitute everything apart from digits with NULL and printing 3rd column then.

Comment: thanks for reply, I have actually changed the command as follows          CATALINA_HOME='/opt26/hpws24/tomcat12'        version=$(echo "$CATALINA_HOME" | cut -d '/' -f 3 | tr -cd [:digit:])            echo $version -----------but my issue is in future if directory structure is changed than searching 3rd field using cut will not work. so i need the string search hpws and extract the remaining digit after it which the tr will be doing, so how to search the string hpws24(any number) from any directory structure?

Comment: @RajSingh, ok in case you need to search it then try something like: `echo "$catahome" | awk 'match($0,/hwps[0-9]+/){print substr($0,RSTART+4,RLENGTH-4)}'` try this once and let me know how it goes?

Comment: Hi I received space not any number.

Comment: @RajSingh, there was spelling typo try `echo "$catahome" | awk 'match($0,/hpws[0-9]+/){print substr($0,RSTART+4,RLENGTH-4)}'` once and let me know then.

Answer (score 1):

You did a small mistake

```
version=$(echo "$catalina_home" | grep -o -E '[0-9]+')
```

should be

```
version=$(echo "$catahome" | grep -o -E '[0-9]+')
```

Here the output that i got

```
nabil@LAPTOP~$ catahome='/opt/hpws24/tomcat'
nabil@LAPTOP:~$ version=$(echo "$catahome" | grep -o -E '[0-9]+')
nabil@LAPTOP:~$ echo $version
24
```

Comment: thanks for reply, I have actually changed the command as follows CATALINA_HOME='/opt26/hpws24/tomcat12'
version=$(echo "$CATALINA_HOME" | cut -d '/' -f 3 | tr -cd [:digit:])
echo $version -----------but my issue is in future if directory structure is changed than searching 3rd field using cut will not work. so i need the string search hpws and extract the remaining digit after it which the tr will be doing, so how to search the string  hpws24(any number) from any directory structure?